# angularJS: nested ng-repeat, orderBy not working

Tags: angularjs

I am working with angular trying to use orderBy on a nested ng-repeat (on both of them), but not being successful. Please take a look:

here is my view:

```
<article class="unaTienda"
    ng-repeat="tienda in resumenesRondaInventariosPorTienda | orderBy: ID_CO" >
    <h3 class='bold'>{{tienda[0][0].nombreTienda}}</h3>
    <article class="unDocumento" ng-repeat="documento in tienda[$index]" >
        <h3>{{documento.tipoDocumento}} {{documento.numeroDocumento}}</h3>
    </article>
</article>
```

This is my model for that view, $scope.resumenesRondaInventariosPorTienda:

```
    {  
   "0":[  
      [  
         {  
            "ID_CO":20,
            "nombreTienda":"GIRARDOT",
            "fechaDocumento":"20151204",
            "tipoDocumento":"IF",
            "numeroDocumento":1,
            "unidades":-12,
            "pesos":-128517
         },
         {  
            "ID_CO":20,
            "nombreTienda":"GIRARDOT",
            "fechaDocumento":"20180409",
            "tipoDocumento":"IF",
            "numeroDocumento":16,
            "unidades":5,
            "pesos":28870
         }
      ]
   ],
   "1":[  
      [  
         {  
            "ID_CO":2,
            "nombreTienda":"PLAZA CAICEDO",
            "fechaDocumento":"20160115",
            "tipoDocumento":"IF",
            "numeroDocumento":1,
            "unidades":-8,
            "pesos":84701
         },
         {  
            "ID_CO":2,
            "nombreTienda":"PLAZA CAICEDO",
            "fechaDocumento":"20180417",
            "tipoDocumento":"IF",
            "numeroDocumento":16,
            "unidades":-6,
            "pesos":-59361
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: you might need `... | orderBy: 'ID_CO'`

Comment: that doesn't work, it's nested

Comment: then you need a custom filter with a sorting method

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.resumenesRondaInventariosPorTienda` is an object where it should be an array.

Re-manipulate your data

```
$scope.final = [];
for(var x in $scope.resumenesRondaInventariosPorTienda)
{
  $scope.final.push($scope.resumenesRondaInventariosPorTienda[x]);
}
```

Then in your view it should be like this

```
<article ng-repeat="tienda in final | orderBy: tienda[$index].ID_CO" >
    <article class="unDocumento" ng-repeat="documento in tienda | filter:busqueda" >
        <h3>{{documento.tipoDocumento}} {{documento.numeroDocumento}}</h3>
    </article>
</article>
```

Comment: thank you, I just changed it to an array 5 min ago, realized the same thing. Will apply your code to view and check if it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

John's got it right in that it'd be best to put your object data into an array first, then order it in the markup (much easier). I was operating under the assumption you couldn't mess with the data structure...

So! If you ever need to do a **custom filter function** -- here you go:

[Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/J9dZJVxyf6Okucam2phR/)

```js
// I like to wrap my JS files in IIFE's per the John Papa Style Guide

(function() {

  "use strict";

  let app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.filter('resumenes', resumenesFunc);

  app.controller('myCtrl', myCtrlFunc);

  myCtrlFunc.$inject = ["$scope"];

  // Custom Filter Function
  function resumenesFunc() {
    return function(resumenes) {
      let resumenesArr = [];

      // Putting the resumenes into a single Array
      for (let resumenIndex in resumenes) {
        let innerArr = resumenes[resumenIndex];

        innerArr.forEach(r => {
          resumenesArr.push(r);
        })
      }

      return resumenesArr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.numeroDocumento - b.numeroDocumento;
      });
    }
  }

  // Controller Function
  function myCtrlFunc($scope) {
    $scope.resumenesRondaInventariosPorTienda = {
      "1": [{
        "ID_CO": 1,
        "nombreTienda": "UNICENTRO CALI",
        "fechaDocumento": "20160126",
        "tipoDocumento": "IF",
        "numeroDocumento": 1,
        "unidades": -19,
        "pesos": -213310
      }, {
        "ID_CO": 1,
        "nombreTienda": "UNICENTRO CALI",
        "fechaDocumento": "20180423",
        "tipoDocumento": "IF",
        "numeroDocumento": 16,
        "unidades": -2,
        "pesos": -11485
      }],
      "2": [{
        "ID_CO": 2,
        "nombreTienda": "PLAZA CAICEDO ",
        "fechaDocumento": "20160115",
        "tipoDocumento": "IF",
        "numeroDocumento": 1,
        "unidades": -8,
        "pesos": 84701
      }, {
        "ID_CO": 2,
        "nombreTienda": "PLAZA CAICEDO ",
        "fechaDocumento": "20160223",
        "tipoDocumento": "IF",
        "numeroDocumento": 2,
        "unidades": -25,
        "pesos": -556909
      }]
    }
  }

})()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Test App</title>

  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h2>Custom Filter - Resumenes</h2>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="quantity = 10; cost = 5">
    <article ng-repeat="tienda in resumenesRondaInventariosPorTienda | resumenes">

      <!-- Custom Filter returns an array rather than an object - so no need for the second repeat -->
      <article class="unDocumento">
        <h3>{{tienda.tipoDocumento}} {{tienda.numeroDocumento}}</h3>
      </article>

    </article>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that the custom filter returns an array of resumenes -- so note that I took out your second `ng-repeat` in the markup. We're doing all the work in the filter function for this data object...no reason for us to add extra markup.

**Disclaimer**: I did not go into crazy detail (aka error handling and such; you can add those as you need).  =)